# PXE booting a syslinux Kernel

Tags: boot, server, pxe, syslinux

I got a small Problem with my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server.

At first i've installed this packages on my server : `dhcp3-server` , `tftpd-hpa` , `nfs-kernel-server` and `syslinux`.

Everything runs fine and i've already made a working memtest boot with a complete menu.

My Nfs Folder is `/nfsroot/`. My tftp Folder is `/var/lib/tftpboot/`. 
Furthermore there is the config Folder `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg` and the default File `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`.

My Boot Menu is made with menu.c32.

My Problem is now  that i want to boot another syslinux kernel with my PXE-server. 
I want to boot syslinux with every Computer in my network.
The Problem is that i dont know how the Append line for the menu.c32 has to look like and what i have to download additionally.
I've already downloaded the latest syslinux Kernel (6.03) to the root of my Server,

A tutorial for that would be nice. 
Pls help me :(

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default `

Answer (score 0):

- You can add new menu entry to  `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` and Change `DEFAULT` to point to the new kernel entry.

  ```
  DEFAULT partmagic 

  LABEL partmagic 
      MENU LABEL PartMagic 4.5 
      KERNEL pmagic/bzimage 
      APPEND initrd=pmagic/initramfs edd=off noapic load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw vga=791 sleep=10 loglevel=0 keymap=us livemedia
  ```
- If you are using a complicated menu template, try search for menu text:

  ```
  grep -nir `LABEL` /var/lib/tftpboot/
  ```

  Then append the new menu entry where you find the old one.
- Concerning manual, see `/usr/share/doc/syslinux-common/txt/menu.txt.gz`.

  There are many other manuals with nice examples in `/usr/share/doc/syslinux-common/`.